# Numeros aleaotrios JavaScript con arrays

Tags: javascript, bucles, random

Necesito hacer un programa con el siguiente enunciado y no consigo sacaralo. Alguien me ayuda?
Hacer un codigo que genere un numero de 4 cifras (no debe de repetirse ninguna de ellas). Se introducira otro numero de 4 cifras (sin repetir ninguna) y se comparará con el generado anteriormente.
Si coincide la cifra y la posicion se indicara con el signo "+", si coincide solo la cifra (y no la posicion) se indicara el signo "-".
Este es mi codigo, no funciona correctamente:

```
var numero = "";
var numeroAleatorio = [];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numeroAleatorio[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (numeroAleatorio[i] == numeroAleatorio[j]) {
            i -= 1;
        }

    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numero += numeroAleatorio[i];
}


numero = parseInt(numero);
document.write("El numero a adivinar era: " + numero);



alert("Hola, en este programa deberás adivinar un numero de 4 cifras distintas. \n Deberas introducir las cifras del numero por separado \n Tienes 10 intentos \n ¡MUCHA SUERTE!");


var numerosIntroducidos = [];
var contador = "";
var respuesta;
var intentos = 0;


while (numeroAleatorio != numerosIntroducidos) {

    intentos++
    alert("Intento" + intentos)

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        respuesta = prompt("Ingresa la cifra" + " " + i + ":");
        numerosIntroducidos.push(respuesta);

    }


    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        contador += numerosIntroducidos[i];

    }

    contador = parseInt(contador);
    alert("Numero introducido " + contador + "\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < numeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < numerosIntroducidos.length; j++) {
            if (numeroAleatorio[i] == numerosIntroducidos[j]) {
                if (i == j) {
                    alert('+');

                } else
                    alert('-');

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta a tu ejercicio me animé a hacerla y probarla, y como resultado quedó el siguiente código:

```js
//input en donde el usuario ingresa el su número
const numberInput = document.getElementById('number');

// variable de número aleatorio
let randomNumber = '';

//generando el número aleatorio sin cifras repetidas
while (randomNumber.length < 4) {
  const newFigure = Math.round(Math.random() * 9).toString();
  if (randomNumber.indexOf(newFigure) === -1) {
    randomNumber += newFigure;
  }
}

//evento de cuando el usuario de click en el botón
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  //guardammos la variables de la etiqueta "p" en donde nos comunicamos con el usuario
  const message = document.getElementById('message');
  //guardamos el número ingresado
  const number = numberInput.value.trim();

  //mensaje de error si el número no es de 4 cifras
  if (number.length !== 4) {
    message.innerText = 'Por favor ingrese un número de 4 cifras';
    return;
  }

  //validamos si el número no tiene cifras repetidas con un for
  let validNumber = true;

  for (let i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) {
    //si esta condición es verdadera significa que el número
    //está repetido
    if (number.indexOf(number[i]) !== i) {
      validNumber = false;
    }
  }

  //si no es un número válido lo decimos y nos devolvemos
  if (!validNumber) {
    message.innerText = 'El número ingresado tiene cifras repetidas';
    return;
  }

  //por último generamos el patrón
  let patron = '';
  for (let i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) {
    if (number[i] === randomNumber[i]) {
      patron += '+';
    } else {
      patron += '-';
    }
  }

  //imprimimos el patrón
  message.innerText = `El patrón del resultado es: ${patron}`;
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>introduce un número a adivinar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Por favor ingresa un número de 4 cifras</h1>
    <input type="number" placeholder="número" id="number" />
    <p id="message"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Comprobar" id="submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver el código está bastante comentado, pero igual te lo explicaré con más detalle dado que eso se nos exige.

Primero para generar el número aleatorio lo que hago primero es generar un número el uno al 4 con [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) * 9, luego ese número me dará probablemente un decimal, y lo que hago es redondearlo con [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), después lo que hago es revisar si ese número a insertar ya existe en el número aleatorio, si existe pues simplemente no lo pongo, y si existe si lo pongo.

Luego cuando el usuario da click sobre el botón simplemente verifico por un lado que tenga 4 cifras con [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length), y luego lo recorro para verificar con [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), si el número se repite.

Ahora, si el número pasa las validaciones simplemente procedo a crear el patrón, de manera que si la cifra coincide, pongo un "+" y si no un "-".

Comment: ¿Porqué el número generado sólo tiene cifras del 0 al 4? Además, en tu respuesta argumentas: _lo que hago primero es generar un número el uno al 4 con Math.random * 4_, cosa que no es correcto, ya que `Math.random() * 4` generará valores entre 0 y 4 (sin incluir el 4). Pero lo que me llama la atención es el porqué generar sólo valores en este rango, el OP no dice nada sobre los valores generados, excepto que sean de 4 cifras. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, hola, disculpa, me equivoqué ejjejeje, ya lo corregí, en realidad debería de ser por 9, para que me dé un número de 9 cifras

Comment: @JesúsGarcía Muchas gracias por dedicarle tiempo a mi consulta. Hay cosas de tu código que aún no conozco, pero te lo agradezco, lo voy a estudiar para entender bien su funcionamiento con tus explicaciones. Gracias!!